# Angular2 routing with parametrs

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to make routing according to the submitted variable. It works when I click once on my button, but when I click it next time I got following error:

```
  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
    at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.
```

Where's the problem? How solve it? Here's code:

gallery.component html:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <button 
        class="button" 
        (click)=
        "
            onChangeModelsTeamClick('female');
            onSelect();   
        "
        [ngClass]="{'active': chosenModels=='female'}" 

    >
        MODELKI
    </button><!--
 --><button 
        class="button"
        (click)=
        "
            onChangeModelsTeamClick('male');
            onSelect();
        "
        [ngClass]="{'active': chosenModels=='male'}" 
    >
        MODELE
    </button><!--
 --><button 
        class="button"
        (click)="
            onChangeModelsTeamClick('premium');
            onSelect();  
        "
        [ngClass]="{'active': chosenModels=='premium'}" 
    >
        PREMIUM
    </button>
</nav>
```

gallery.component.ts

```
onSelect() {
    this._router.navigate(['/galeria', this.chosenModels]);
}
```

app routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'galeria', component: GalleryComponent  },
    { path: 'galeria/:id', component: TeamDemonstrationComponent  }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
export const routingComponents = [GalleryComponent, TeamDemonstrationComponent];
```

Comment: how do you attach the `this.chosenModels`  and can you show this method `onChangeModelsTeamClick()`